# Is Rama called ekapatni vrata in any scripture?

Tags: rama, name, reference-request, itihasa

There is circumstantial evidence suggesting he was ekapatnivrata (took only one wife) - but is he explicitly called that in any Ramayana or other scriptures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Ekapatni vratam* does not appear to be an epithet of Rama, but he is clearly described in that way in the Padma Purana. (5.105.51)

> **ekapatnīvrataṃ** jñātvā rāmaṃ te samupāgaman |
> athavepitasarvāṃgaṃ skhalatpadagatiṃ nṛpam ||
>
> **Knowing Rāma to be one devoted to his only wife**, they came to the king (i.e. Rāma) whose entire body was trembling and whose steps were faltering.

[Garga Samhita 5.11.3](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/garga-samhita-english/d/doc1125654.html) has a similar reference:

> nirmohaṃ rāghavaṃ dṛṣṭvā-
> tha**ika-patnī-vrata**-sthitaṃ
> krodhāt sītāṃ bhakṣayituṃ
> dhāvatī rāvaṇa-svasā
>
> Seeing that **Lord Rāma had vowed to accept only one wife**, and had not fallen in love with her, Rāvaṇa's sister Śūrpanakhā angrily ran to devour Sītā-devī.